# Reading multiple excel workbooks from a subdirectory into one dataframe

Tags: r

This command allows me to read all of the .xlsx files from the current directory into the dataframe.

```
df <- map_df(list.files(), ~ read_xlsx(., col_types = 
              c("text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
                "text", "numeric", "text")))
```

The problems is that I would like to put all of the excel files into a subdirectory called files, such that it would change like this

```
 df <- map_df(list.files("files"), ~ read_xlsx(., col_types = 
                  c("text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
                    "text", "numeric", "text")))
```

This creates a problem as far as the path is concerned, since the list files reads from the "files" directory, and the path does not have files/first.xlsx, but first.xlsx, which creates a problem reading the files from the read_xlsx command.  What do I change in the read_xlsx to make sure when it is reading the list of files, it will add the subdirectory titled "files"?

Comment: Try `list.files("./files")`

Comment: Also see the documentation for `?list.files` where the argument `full.names` is mentioned.